# Sublime text 2 - broken letter

Tags: windows, character, sublimetext, polish

I am using Sublime text 2 and I can type all polish letters (even `Ł`) beside `ł`.
That is strange, because there are not any keyboard shortcuts with `Alt_gr + L` (That's the way I type it). Nothing comes up when I am trying to type it.

I am working on English Windows 7 x64 with Polish keyboard layout. And I can type `ł` in all other programs. So I am guessing it is program fault.

Comment: It works fine in ST2 for me, using ENG keyboard, i can get the ł no problems...

Comment: @fraxel You mean ENG layout? How are you typing it?

Comment: Same way you described, it seems to just default to it for me.. don't know why! I'm on Ubuntu though...

Answer (score 0):

I know what was wrong. There was a package called automaticbackups. It has keybinding for `Alt+l`. Next time I will check console logs (the way I figured out).

Answer (score 0):

Im a Windows user and I started to use Sublime Text 2 instead of Notepadd++ just to see if it fits my needs. I had some problems with settings proper encoding for polish letters myself (setting "Central European (Windows 1250)" fixed most of the displaying problems). Just recently I also noticed that I can not enter polish letter ł (AltGr+l - polish (programmer) keyboard settings on Win 7 x64). Problem was connected with SublimeLinter package.

To fix this I had to change line in Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter -> Key Bindings - Default:
`{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+l"], "command": "sublimelinter", "args": {"action": "lint"} }`,

As all experts know and I just found out Ctrl+Alt ≈ AltGr (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)